# Yes/No Type in SharePoint List doesn't export to CSV

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm having a bit of trouble when I'm transferring List data to CSV. The list has four columns

- Title
- Age
- Gender
- SPMember

The first three have are just Strings but the SPMember is a Yes/No type. The exported CSV has doesn not have any data on the SP Member column. I tried using toString() method but apparently it returns null. I'm not sure if this is the normal behavior when it comes to Yes/No columns but any workaround/fix would he helpful.

Here's my code:

```
function ExportList($siteUrl, $clientContext, $listN, $txtPath, $exportFile)
{ 

$aQuery = New-Object ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())

$listItem = $listN.GetItems($aQuery)
$clientContext.Load($listItem)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$itemCollection = @() 

Write-Host "Creating CSV report" -ForegroundColor Cyan


 foreach ($item in $listItem) {

    $exportItem = New-Object PSObject
    $count = 0

    foreach ($cname in $txtPath){
     Log $txtPath[$count]
     Log $item[$txtPath[$count]].ToString()
     $exportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $txtPath[$count] -Value $item[$txtPath[$count]]
     $count++ 
    }
     $itemCollection += $exportItem
 }
#Export the result Array to CSV file
$itemCollection | Export-CSV $exportFile -NoTypeInformation

Write-host "Done!"  -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

$listN is the name of the list.
$txtPath is a the path to a txt file that contains the headers.

Comment: Please consider providing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the field internal name is "SPMember".

I create a test list and add Yes/No field "SPMember", then using the PowerShell below to export list items to a csv file.

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

##Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lz"
$ListName="TestYesNo"
$ExportFile ="D:\ListRpt.csv"
$UserName="lz@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password ="***"

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))

#Set up the context
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Context.Credentials = $credentials

#Get the List
$List = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)

#Get All List Items
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
$context.Load($ListItems)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

#Array to Hold List Items
$ListItemCollection = @()

#Fetch each list item value to export to excel
 $ListItems |  foreach {
    $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $_["Title"]
    if($_["SPMember"] -eq "TRUE"){
        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SPMember" -value "Yes"
    }else{
        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SPMember" -value "No"
    }    
    #Add the object with above properties to the Array
    $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
 }
#Export the result Array to CSV file
$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV $ExportFile -NoTypeInformation

Write-host "List data Exported to CSV file successfully!"
```

[image]